# Bootstrap datetimepicker get time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am using [Bootstrap datetimepicker](https://github.com/tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker) in a form insider my Meteor.JS app in order to have two time picker elements. Below is the code I have so far which detect the onChange event for each of the two time picker elements in my form but I can't figure out how to get the selected time? So can someone please tell me how to do so? Thanks

```
 $('.set-start-time').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false
 });
 $('.set-end-time').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false
 });    

$('.set-end-time').on("dp.change",function (e) {
    var now  = $('.set-start-time').data("DateTimePicker").getDate();
    var then = $('.set-end-time').data("DateTimePicker").getDate(); 
    //Above code won't return time...

});
```

Comment: GetDate function will return only Date. What you can try is convert date object to string using **toLocaleString**. Following is the output format: _12/2/2014, 9:22:45 PM_ and then you can split the string from ','.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps some one.

HTML

```
<div name="startTime" class="input-group time">
   <input  class="form-control" type="text" value="" >
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
  $('.time').datetimepicker({
      format: 'LT'
  }).on("dp.change",function(e){
      var date = e.date;//e.date is a moment object
      var target = $(e.target).attr('name');
      console.log(date.format("HH:mm:ss"))//get time by using format
  })
```

e.date is a moment object thus time can derived by using format("HH:mm:ss")