# Insert Selected date from bootstrap datetime picker into input field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I have my DateTimePicker:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 FormDownDateSelect" style="height: 100%; background-color: #EDEADE ">
    <div id="datetimepicker1"></div>
</div>
```

And when I select a Date I would like to add the selected date into this Input Field

```
<input readonly="readonly" class="input-field2" value="Vælg Dato"><span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
```

I have tried stuff like this:

```
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,
            format: "dd MM yyyy",

        }).bind('dateSelected', function (e, selectedDate, $td) {
            alert(selectedDate);
        });
    });
```

I cant even get it to alert the selected date. Can someone help?

[Plugin](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0oLo2s1/)

Comment: which `datetimepicker` you are using? Hope there should be link to some plugin?

Comment: put your code into http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have these scripts/css in order

- You can find the datetimepicker CDN [here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker)
- You can find the Moment CDN [here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/)
- You can find the boostrap CDN [here](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Moment.js (if you're using time) needs to be loaded first, then the CSS files, then bootstrap.js, then the bootstrap.datetimepicker.js

As far as you not getting your values from the date picker, **that's b/c you're not using the correct event** for the `datetimepicker` plugin.

You need to use `dp.change` instead of `dateSelected`. This is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253392/bootstrap-datetimepicker-get-time) on getting the time (as well as the event).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65as4dxd/) for you as well

Answer (score 0):

modified

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        format: "dd MM yyyy",

    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('.input-field2').val(e.date);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0oLo2s1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dp.change` while binding an event to your `datepicker` and then you can fetch formatted date using `moment.js` as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t0oLo2s1/1/)**, **[Docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange)**

```
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,
            format: "dd MM yyyy",

        }).bind('dp.change', function (e, selectedDate, $td) {
            $('.input-field2').val(moment(e.date._d).format("dd MM YYYY"))
        });
});
```